# VS Code: Looking for an axtension to group other extensions by programming language

Tags: visual-studio-code

Okay, I know the title is not very clear, but is hard to describe what I need, so I'll try to describe it better:

I use a lot of programming languages due to my studies at the university, and my favorite editor is visual studio. The problem is, I don't want to overload it with a lot of active extensions at the same time. Therefore, the idea I came up with is an extension that creates "sessions" (or something like that) depending on what programming language I want to use. For example, imagine I want to use python, then I'd turn on an option which will enable the extensions needed for python and it will disable the remaining ones.

I can't find any similar extension on Google, I don't know if I am using the correct keywords for that, though. So, if you know of something that will help me, let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, Visual Studio Code has developed a function that allows us to have different profiles (this is shown on the gear icon on the bottom left).

With this feature, we can add different profiles, each with different settings, extensions, etc. This way, we can have a profile for work and another for personal projects, for example, or one for coding with Java and another with Python.